# Using std::optional to avoid potentially unitialized variable?

Tags: c++

Visual Studio generates spurious "potentially uninitialized variable" for code like:

```
   bool oldValue; // Uninitialized
   bool haveValue=false;
   for(...) {
      ...
      if (...) {
         bool  value=...;
         if (haveValue && value!=oldValue) {
           // Do something
         }
         haveValue=true;
         oldValue=value;
      }
    }
```

Since we have tools that dynamically detect if a variable is used uninitialized I don't want to introduce a dummy default value, but I realized that using std::optional would be a possibility.

Is that possible, efficient, and good practice?

If so is it possible to make it more efficient than this:

```
   std::optional<bool> oldValue; // Default-initialized
   for(...) {
      ...
      if (...) {
         bool  value=...;
         if (oldValue.hasValue() && value!=oldValue.value()) {
           // Do something
         }
         oldValue=value;
      }
    }
```

Comment: why not just `bool oldValue = false;`? This will inhibit detection of use of uninitialized just like the optional, no?

Comment: Yes it's a very good practice.

Comment: It seems clearer to me (I would use `if (oldValue && value != *oldValue)` as preference style).

Comment: What do you mean with `Default-initialized` comment of optional?

Comment: If this is not micro-optimization, I would consider to handle the first value separate. I.e. you might store the first input into `oldValue` directly, and start the loop with the 2nd input. There might be some additional tests necessary (e.g. to check whether more than one input value is available or even one) but these are single checks outside of the loop. Maybe, I'm paranoid but a periodical check in a loop which is actually needed once only and just a waste for all other iterations would annoy me.

Comment: @Scheff - It's not necessarily the first value in the loop, but the first value meeting some criteria.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 - Because we use tools that actually detect if oldValue is used incorrectly in test-cases(not merely that it might be) and that would defeat that testing.

Comment: yes I think thats the part I understood. I just don't understand how you can still check in a meaningful way with the optional. Though, nevermind, maybe I just don't see the obvious, by no means I wanted to imply "hey, why are you asking this question?!?"

Comment: _It's not necessarily the first value in the loop, but the first value meeting some criteria._ Hmm... One loop to find the first value. Another loop for comparing with other values?

Comment: If `haveValue` and `oldValue` are tightly coupled, and if their combined meaning correlates to the semantic meaning of `std::optional` then it is absolutely a reason for replacing your two variables with an `std::optional`.

Comment: @Jarod42 `std::optional` has overload for `operator!=` so you can just do: `if (value != oldValue)`.

Comment: @MarekR: More controversial usage for `std::optional<bool>` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically your initial implementation is kind of optional implementation done in place.
I would not be surprised if generated code would be exactly same (with [gcc they are not](https://godbolt.org/z/Yzsv8GPrr), but very similar and std::optional version looks better, for [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/cWaEb4c5G) differences are minimal still code for optional looks better).

This change will make code more readable and easier to maintain, nothing else. So go for it.

BTW, small improvement:

```cpp
   std::optional<bool> oldValue;
   for(...) {
      ...
      if (...) {
         bool  value=...;
         if (oldValue != value) { //optional has proper overload
           // Do something
         }
         oldValue=value;
      }
    }
```

Note also there is [std::unique_copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique_copy)